# Text Field Commands (Android) (Java)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a text field command in my Android Studio project.  I have a text field and when I type a keyword some code will run.  So a 'else if statement'

I have created this in Objective-C for a iOS project earlier. Here is the code from their

```
-(void) perform: (NSString *) command {
    // WithOut WhiteSpace (Text Control)
    if([command caseInsensitiveCompare:@"ROTATE"] == NSOrderedSame) // Command Rotate
    {
        [pattern decreaseAngle];
        int f = [pattern getAngle];
        [self changeAngle:(f)];
    }
```

Now, i need to do the same-thing but in java for my Android App. How can i create a else-if statement in Java for a text field?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Objective-C or iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for if else in java is :

```
if (strcmp(string1, string2) == 0) {
// Do something.
}
else{
// Do something else
}
```

See JAVA String functions like `strcmp` which are used to compare strings.